# How do we disable Azure Api Management developer portal (both legacy and new)

Tags: azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I worked with a team today who wanted to disable the developer portal and the signup.

The best we could come up with was to disable the legacy developer portal by adding delegation to a static site as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-setup-delegation

I did some testing and the new developer portal can be disabled by removing all the providers including username and password from the identities blade. This means going to the new portal returns "Developer portal has not been published yet." I think I read that the new portal would be optional somewhere.

**Does anyone know a the correct way to disable the legacy and new developer portals?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have found in my own research, Azure API Management does not have a way to disable either the legacy or new dev portals. There is a roadmap item for an Unpublish feature for the new dev portal at the following address:
https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/projects/4#card-28534235

As this link will likely not last very long, here is a screenshot of the referenced roadmap item:

[image]

As an alternative to removing the identity providers, you can use the Azure APIM Management REST API to toggle the "properties.enabled" portal setting. Instructions are available at this link: https://blog.bitscry.com/2019/11/07/disabling-signup-in-the-azure-api-management-developer-portal/

Note that when this setting is changed to enabled = false, both sign up and sign in are disabled on the legacy dev portal (I don't know if the new dev portal respects this setting).

What can also be done in the legacy dev portal is to modify the Sign In and Sign Up templates to remove their respective forms, preventing anyone from being able to perform either action. Removing the relevant widgets from the respective pages in the new dev portal may also be feasible (or possibly delete the Sign In and Sign Up pages complete and remove from the Navigation list).

Comment: Thanks Kevin - great link